# SSIS Package to upload, download, and edit files on Sharepoint Online with OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, ssis, sharepoint-online

I hope someone can point out what I am doing wrong. I am trying to connect to an instance of SharePoint Online which uses OAuth2. I have created a script task in SSIS with the following code:
[image]

I am getting an error at the AquireTokenForClient step:

[image]

I'm not sure if my code is incorrect or the Azure auth is incomplete.
I appreciate any advice. Thanks!

As suggested, here is the actual code:

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.IO;
#endregion

namespace ST_df8805573a0f4f25a5273ec3fd1226f2

    private const string ClientId = "11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555";
    private const string ClientSecret = "66666666-7777-8888-9999-000000000000";
    private const string TenantId = "11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555";
    private const string SharePointSiteUrl = "https://companyname.sharepoint.com/:f:/r/sites/SoftwareApplicationsandDatabaseSite/Shared%20Documents/Test?csf=1&web=1&e=HED8nA";
    private const string RelativeFilePath = "/sites/SoftwareApplicationsandDatabaseSite/Shared%20Documents/Test?csf=1&web=1&e=HED8nA"; // Example path
    private const string Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + TenantId;

    public void Main()
    {
        // Obtain the access token using MSAL
        var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
            .WithAuthority(Authority)
            .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
            .Build();

        string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://companyname.sharepoint.com/.default" };

        var authResult = confidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;
        var accessToken = authResult.AccessToken;

        // Use the access token to connect to SharePoint Online and download the file
        using (var ctx = new ClientContext(SharePointSiteUrl))
        {
            ctx.ExecutingWebRequest += (sender, e) => e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + accessToken;

            //var fileRef = RelativeFilePath;
            //var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, fileRef);

            //using (var fileStream = new FileStream("downloadedFile.txt", FileMode.Create))
            //{
            //    fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            //}

            Console.WriteLine("File downloaded successfully!");
        }
    }
    //{
        

    //  Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    //}
```

Looks like I need a Certificate. I will try that next.

Errors are:
System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred.'

1. HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
2. WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
3. IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
4. SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: You should paste text content to the question.

Comment: Please paste the error as text. Also since this is a C# heavy solution, consider building in a C# native platform like a console app rather than SSIS

Comment: I tried a console app using PnP and I am getting "WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized". I think I might not have the correct permissions in Azure.

Comment: I was able to get an access token in a console app using PnP Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get an access token in a console app using PnP Framework.